# Drawing ER-Diagram using alternative packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, database

I have found some packages to draw ER-Diagrams using Tikz, but I don't like the final result (it has big rhombuses for associations, big ovals for attributes and so on). I'd like to draw ER-diagram like the following one

[image]

using these shapes

[image]

I am not able to find any package in order to get this result. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462914/how-to-create-an-er-diagram-using-tikzpicture-environment  --  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164422/making-the-tikz-drawinger-diagram-looking-nicer

Comment: The first link is about an er-diagram where an entity is represented by a table and the attributes as its rows (while I'd like to represent them as little circles linked to the rectangle, which symbolizes the entity). The second one is exactly the er-diagram I wish to avoid.

Comment: See [Drawing relationships between elements of a database](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78357/13304) for a pretty detailed list of options.

Comment: have you found a solution? I'd like to use that style too

Comment: [TikZ-UML](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php) exists but I don't think it has necessarily all these specific things.

Comment: @PaoloCotto The problem for me with these questions is that it's not clear what's a shape and what's just and addition. It looks like the small circles aren't part of a shape but an flexible addition. Are the lines from one side around the shape to another side part of the shape or do they somehow specify something of those small circles?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the MetaPost `expressg` package which provides facilities to assist in drawing box-line-annotation (BLA) diagrams such as EXPRESS-G, IDEF1X, OMT, Shlaer-Mellor, NIAM, ER, UML and similar diagrams.

On my `texlive` installation doing `texdoc expressg` will result in several different examples of its possibilities. To see if it is on your installation do `kpsewhich expressg.mp`. It can be downloaded from https://ctan.org/pkg/expressg